# Crystal Reports Logon Failed Error With Network Path But OK With Mapped Drive

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, dao

I have a VB6 program that gets installed locally on workstations. It uses an Access database, usually over a peer to peer network. I have crystal reports embedded in the program and it accesses its .rpt files from the same folder on the "server" that the database is located in.  The reports files are created with "same as report" selected as the data source path.  I pass the actual database path at runtime when the report is called up.

This has worked perfectly for a very long time with only one hitch I'd like to fix.  I have to pass crystal reports a mapped drive.  It won't work with a network path.  If I use T:\Towtrack.mdb  it runs happily.  If I use \SERVER\Towtrack\Towtrack.mdb it returns a "logon failed" error.  Since Micrsoft has broken DAO and mapped drives produce constant database corruptions I need to get away from them.

(database(s) and .rpt files are all in the same folder on the server and the entire folder has full control permissions with an "everyone" user)

Comment: *Since Micrsoft has broken DAO and mapped drives produce constant database corruptions* if you want to assert something that is likely to be wrong you need proof.

Comment: The machine name needs to be preceded with double backslashes, not a single backslash.  Also, the user needs to have permission, which would have been handled during the mapping but not necessarily during the dynamic UNC, so it might be a permissions problem.

Comment: It is in with double backslashes.  Either formatting took one out when I posted the question, or I forgot to type one here.   The same path is used by the rest of the program successfully, it just fails with Crystal.   Thank You though!